# How to pass username and password in authorization in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication, postman

I want to make post request, but I don't know how to send these username and password from Postman in Laravel.

```
 $response = Http::withHeaders([
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                //'Authorization' => $access_token 
            ])->post(
  
                $url.'/wp-json/wc/v3/products',

                 [
                'product'=>$product
                
            ]);
```

[image]

Comment: If it is Basic Auth, there's a [`withBasicAuth`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client#authentication) method

Comment: Do you necessarily want to use postman? Maybe this helps: https://mevelix.com/articles/postman-auth-for-laravel,4

Basically, you want to login via browser, take the laravel_session value from the cookie in the browser and paste it into your request. I've used this for 3rd party websites as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this example helps you

```
 $response = Http::withBasicAuth('User', 'Password')
->accept('application/json')
->post($url,[
            'Key A' => 'Value A',
            'Key B' => 'Value B'
        ]
    );
```